# Javascript - count and remove from an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with duplicate values and I want to count all those which have the same value and remove them.

```
var myArray = [{nr: 'bbc',}, {nr: 'bbc'}, {nr: 'bbc'}, {nr: ccc}];
```

from this array I want to create another array but remove the duplicated values and count them to be like this.

```
var myArray = [{nr: 'bbc',amount: 3}}, {nr: ccc,amount: 1}];
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Why are you storing as {nr:'bbc'} instead of just storing a list of the 'bbc'

Comment: I need something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same structure, this will work for you

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var matched = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
        if(myArray[i].nr === newArray[j].nr){
            matched = true;
            newArray[j].amount++;
            break;
        }
    };
    if(!matched)
        newArray.push({nr:myArray[i].nr,amount:1});
};
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a better format

```
var count = {};
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
  if(typeof count[myArray[i].nr] == 'undefined') {
    count[myArray[i].nr] = 0;
  }

  ++count[myArray[i].nr];
}
```

and this wound yield somehing like:

```
count = {
  bcc: 3,
  ccc: 1
};
```

if you still need it with the structure you specified, then:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var k in count) {
  newArray.push({
    nr: k,
    amount: count[k]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that will but I need a array with the key and the amount in the same obj.